# Crash when call @IBAction func in secondViewController file

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying out a few concepts about segues. So I created `secondViewController` and `thirdViewController`, I also created a ViewController file for `secondViewController`. Then I add a button on `secondViewController` and some codes to `secondViewController.swift`. Here is the code, quite simple:

```
import UIKit

class secondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func onNext(sender: AnyObject) {
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdViewController")
            showViewController(vc, sender: self)
        }
    }
```

After building and running,when I tap on the "next" button,it crashed.

```
2016-02-21 14:28:24.244 test[4176:476944] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController onNext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fea72c48e20'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f795e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001114d5deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f79e48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6eb90a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6eb4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ffb4194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001101236fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001101239c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110122af8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x000000011002349b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001100241d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ffd2b66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ffacd97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6c1a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6b795c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6b6e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6b6828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113dabad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010ffb2610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  test                                0x000000010f5b750d main + 109
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111fde92d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have ViewController with **thirdViewController** as identifier set up in storyboard? What does the `showViewController` do? Can you log the exception in detail?

Comment: Yes,I have set a identifier for thirdViewController, do you mean that? `showViewController` present a view controller in a primary context. I just logged the exception in detail.

Comment: Can you check in your storyboard if you have properly connected the IBAction `onNext:` to the button?

Comment: Control-click the button and drag it to the secondViewController file,is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by checking the identifier of thirdViewController again(fount it wrong) and corrected it.I‘m too careless.I think `unrecognized selector sent to instance` is a very important clue to figure this out.